# Python 3.65 Anaconda Jupyter Object not being recognized from previous cells

Tags: python, dataframe

In one cell, I am importing data from a `.csv` file into a pandas DataFrame. Then, in the next cell of the notebook, I am running a default function, `.head()`, which shows the first 5 entries. However, I am getting an error saying: `name 'samples' is not defined`

My code:

```
In[3]:
%%timeit
df201801F = pd.read_csv('01.csv')
df201802F = pd.read_csv('02.csv')
df201803F = pd.read_csv('03.csv')
df201804F = pd.read_csv('04.csv')
df201805F = pd.read_csv('05.csv')
sample201801F = df201801F.sample(n)
sample201802F = df201802F.sample(n)
sample201803F = df201803F.sample(n)
sample201804F = df201804F.sample(n)
sample201805F = df201805F.sample(n)
samples = pd.concat([df201801F, df201802F, df201803F, df201804F, df201805F])

In[4]:
samples.head()
```

In[4] doesn't run. Any ideas why?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you please post the detailed error here?

Comment: do you get same error if you run samples.head() in [3]?

Comment: Remove `%%timeit`, because it is used for check performance

Comment: @jezrael I used to use `%timeit` but I see my type of using two "%".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with using `%%timeit`. All variables are stored temporary, so it is not possible them used later.

Check this sample:

[image: pic]